# java.util.concurrent , examples, tutorial and code

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I've been ask to build a multi-threaded java application using the `java.util.concurrent` library. I'm not familiar with this library, but have a good understanding of problems with multi-threaded code.

I'm looking for a tutorial and example code that shows this java library in use and it's best practises.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are a fast learner, I recommend the site www.java2s.com (Java API by Example).

Here's the full link for the concurrent package: http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.util.concurrent/Catalogjava.util.concurrent.htm

EDIT:
If you can spend some cash (and isn't in a hurry), I recommend this book:
Java Concurrency in Practice
[http://www.amazon.com/Java-Concurrency-Practice-Brian-Goetz/dp/0321349601/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1290021702&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601)

It is really full of examples and good practices.

Comment: +1 The book is great

Comment: +1 as well, I own that book and give it out to college new hire developers, it's the best introduction to Java concurrency

Answer (score 6):

I usually prefer to learn from the primary source and recommend this one:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html

Also I like very much book "Thinking in Java" by Bruce Eckel

Answer (score 4):

You can try my [brief notes](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B2EZFIvnYfEpZGQ0OTgxNTktYThkZC00MWMwLTg4MzctNmNlNGNmMTU1ZGI4) on the subject (it's only 10 pages). I've made this quick tutorial after reading some articles alongside with javadoc for java.util.concurrent.

Answer (score 2):

Vogella's [Java Concurrency / Multithreading Tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html)

Covers the basics (immutable data structures) and all relevant technologies - from `Thread`s over the (Java 6, `java.util.concurrent`) `Executor` framework, and `Future`s/`Callable`s, to the (coming Java 7) *fork/join* framework.

20 printed pages, not the best English, but to the point.

Answer (score 0):

checkout this post. It explains the basics of concurrent design very well.

http://walivi.wordpress.com/2013/08/24/concurrency-in-java-a-beginners-introduction/