# Java equivalent for Python pool.map/ Multiprocessing

Tags: java, python, concurrency, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I was wondering if somebody could point me to a simple equivalent of python's multiprocessing module in java.

I have a simple parallel processing scenario (where no 2 processes interact): Take a data set and split it into 12 and apply a java method to the 12 datasets, collect results and join them in a list of some sort with the same ordering.

Java being a "pro" language appears to have multiple libraries and methods - anyone who can help this java newbie get started?

I would like to do this with minimal of coding - as i said my requirement is pretty straightforward.

Update:
[how to do multiprocessing in java, and what speed gains to expect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001966/how-to-do-multiprocessing-in-java-and-what-speed-gains-to-expect)

This seems to indicate threads is the way to go. I expect I have no choice but wade into a bunch of locks (pun unintended) and wait for my ship to sail. Simple examples are welcome nevertheless.

Comment: You mean like http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html ?

Comment: Possibly - With the multiprocessing module i don't have to think about threads and stuff. I simply map my function across the chunks of data in a list. The concurrent util here seems more complex at least to me. Perhaps there is an example for a simple application that will get me started.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208208/java-util-concurrent-examples-tutorial-and-code this was helpful too - but if there is anything simpler out there would appreciate it.

Comment: http://ricardozuasti.com/2012/java-concurrency-examples-parallel-data-processing/ gets me partway there using the concurrent class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no exactly-compatible class, but [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) gives you everything you need to implement it.

In particular, there's no function to map a `Callable` over a `Collection` and wait on the results, but you can easily build a `Collection<Callable<T>>` out of a `Callable<T>` and `Collection<T>`, then just call `invokeAll`, which returns you a `List<Future<T>>`.

(If you want to emulate some of the other functions from `multiprocessing.Pool`, you will need to loop around `submit` instead and build your own collection of things to wait on. But `map` is simple.)

Comment: That is exactly what I needed - I'll test it tomorrow and may get back with some questions.

Comment: @pythOnometrist: If you want to do anything non-trivial, I'd suggest learning how executors and futures work, instead of trying to build the Python `multiprocessing` API on top of them. You might want to play with Python's own `concurrent.futures` library (or [the backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/futures) if you're on 2.x) to get the hang of the ideas first. A lot of code is actually simpler that way anyway. But also, if you have to use Java, you'll be a lot happier writing idiomatic Java than trying to use Java as a very bad Python…

Comment: I do not understand. How is this multiprocessing? Isn't `ExecutorService` made for `threads` only?