# Can I use swing worker in my J2EE App?

Tags: java, swing, tomcat

I have a sync web application, where data is syncing from one database to another database. For the background process work I have already implemented the swing worker code in my web app. But the web app sometimes does not start. so Can I use swing worker in my J2EE App?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As hinted at by the use of the `javax.swing` package, [javax.swing.SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) is specifically designed for use in Swing applications (it properly interacts with the [EDT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_dispatching_thread), etc.)

If you are writing a webapp, I'd suggest you look at the threading support in [`java.util.concurrent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) instead.

Take a look at [java.util.concurrent , examples, tutorial and code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208208/java-util-concurrent-examples-tutorial-and-code) for links to various tutorials (and a book) on using this package.